# Redundant usage of "the" in names/titles is incorrect?

Tags: grammar, articles

Which is correct?

1) The "The Lord of the Rings" series is popular.

2) "The Lord of the Rings" series is popular.

Comment: Tolkien's title includes the initial determinative: ***The** Lord of the Rings*.

Comment: Arguably those are both pretty darned wrong.

Comment: Best side-stepped by referring to: *The film/TV series, The Lord of the Rings*

Comment: Related: [Homer's “Odyssey”? Homer's “The Odyssey”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238893/homers-odyssey-homers-the-odyssey/238986#238986)

Comment: @RonaldSole What!?  You philistine!  It's a book series.  ;-p

Comment: @Hellion Wasn't when I went to the local cinema .

Comment: 3) The "Lord of the Rings" series is popular. (using deletion)

Comment: @Hellion It's a novel not a series.

Comment: @tchrist Wanna see "pretty darned wrong"? (The "The Lego Movie" movie is awesome.)

Answer (score 1):

> "The Lord of the Rings" series is popular.

When beginning "The" is formal part of title or proper name, it should be treated as normal part of sentence, giving just enough clarification about themselves, no additional articles needed (or allowed).

Additionally, you should **always** capitalize starting "The" of the title (not a case with non-title proper names, like geographic ones).

And, in any case, **you should not** delete it, as it is internal part of the title.